# How do I know a product is in the "will_expire" state?

Tags: python, django, time

I am developing a software system and in it there are time-measured products. The customer buys the product for a period of time, such as one month.

If the user does not list their products everyday, how will I know the product will expire?

If the product has three status: `normal`, `will_expire`, `expired` how can I change the status to `will_expire`, when it has 3 days left to expire? Must I list all the products in the server everyday?

Comment: The customer's computer has a clock/calendar.  Python has ways to access the customer's clock.

Comment: i mean. i am not the customer. i am admin.

Comment: The status of a time-measured product is a function of the expiry date and the current date. If you know those, you can always calculate if the product will expire soon or has already expired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [the classic age problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9788542). You want to know how old your customers  are. Should you check every customer every day to see if it's their birthday?

No. Don't even store anyone's age. Store their birthdate and calculate their age when anyone asks for it.

So don't store `normal`, `will_expire`, or `expired`. Just store the expiration date and calculate which of these three should be displayed whenever anyone asks for it.